# Change Position of Radio Buttons in Qualtrics Survey

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, qualtrics

One of my questions in a qualtrics survey contains a table (6 rows, 2 columns). The question-type is multiple choice (single answer). I would like to change the position of the radio buttons so that they appear in the last row of the table. How can I change the position of the radio buttons?

My current solution is that I create my own radio buttons in HTML:

```
<input name = "response" id = "response-1" type = "radio">
```

Then I use java script to save the choice of repsondents in an embedded data field. I would prefer to use the radio buttons from qualtrics (instead of creating my own buttons), because the responses would be automatically saved in the data set and I can make use of all the other qualtrics question options (such as validation and forced response). Unforutnately, I have no idea how I can move the radio buttons from qualtrics into the question field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is the complete HTML code for the table:

```html
<table>
  <tr><td align="center">A</td><td align="center">A</td></tr>
  <tr><td align="center">A</td><td align="center">A</td></tr>
  <tr><td align="center">A</td><td align="center">A</td></tr>
  <tr><td align="center">A</td><td align="center">A</td></tr>
  <tr><td align="center">A</td><td align="center">A</td></tr>
  <tr><td align="center">A</td><td align="center">A</td></tr>
  <tr><td align="center"><input name = "response" id = "response-1" type="radio"></td><td align="center"><input name = "response" id = "response-2" type="radio"></td></tr>
 </table>
```

Here is the Java Script I currently use (which can probably be improved):

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
$('response-1').observe('click', function(event) {
  var val1 = "1";
 Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("a1", val1);
});
$('response-2').observe('click', function(event) {
  var val1 = "2";
 Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("a1", val1);
});
});
```

Comment: Post all your html and JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added the code to the question.

Comment: Assuming each column describes features of the answer option, have you tried doing it the other way around by putting the information in the table columns in the answer option labels instead? There are a few ways you could do it: embed a single column table, use an unordered list, or just use breaks between the rows.